# what to make with a very high hydration dough?

Tags: dough, bread

I have accidently (due to tiredness and unit-conversion) made what I think is roughly a 100% hydration dough. I have used strong white bread flour. I was intending to make some "no-kneed" bread, so after mixing the ingredients I have left it to rise for 18 hours, and it has been in the fridge for another 24 hours. It is very sticky and runny.

Are there any types of bread that call for a dough of this level of hydration? Is there anything I can use it for? Other than trying to incorporate more flour (which I'm not sure is a good idea this far into the process)? What will happen if I just put in a bread tin and cook it?

Answer (score 5):

I'd try frying it like a pancake in small batches.  You might get a nice soft naan-like flatbread.

OR: Deep fry it like a donut.

Comment: Flatbread? If it was intended for no-knead, it probably included yeast.

Comment: @rumtscho naan has yeast...

Answer (score 4):

Bake it in a dutch oven:
http://www.grouprecipes.com/27935/no-knead-dutch-oven-bread.html

Comment: Loaf or muffin pans might also work to give it some shape as it cooks; I have a high hydration ham & cheese no-knead dough recipe that just needs *something* for support  so it doesn't run all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking from experience...

You can still bake your dough. My boyfriend and I also encountered the same problem once when making no-knead bread - it was unusually runny and sticky. We baked it in our dutch oven anyway, and it was a perfectly good bread. Not as crusty and not as many air bubbles as the no-knead normally has, but tasty nonetheless. A little denser and chewier.

You should also figure out what to do with your dough quickly; our runny batch rose for maybe an extra three or four hours (in our hot, muggy kitchen) and the bread had a slightly sourdough flavor to it. I think the dough started to turn. Yours should be okay since it was in the fridge, but I'd use it today.

Comment: Wait, a sourdough flavor is a bad thing? :-P

Answer (score 3):

You could turn it into pizza bianca, focaccia, or a puffy pizza crust. Spread the dough out on an oiled sheet pan (carefully to avoid losing any trapped CO2), let it rest for ten minutes or so, oil the top and bake. For pizza bianca or focaccia, you might add salt and rosemary to the top. For pizza crust, you'd par-bake it until the crust starts to brown, then add toppings and finish baking.